# Assigning data in array with existing code

Tags: c++, arrays, function, structure

The purpose of this program is to display the transaction and balance.Somehow like this pic.[image] Currently I am struggling about creating RecordDeposit & RecordWithdraw function. I dont know how to store the Transaction parameter into the TransactionList array. Balance and Amount are from different structure, How to combine this two variable and calculate the result to display?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Customer
{
    string CustomerName;
    string UserID;
    string Pin;
};

struct Account
{
    Customer Holder;
    string AccountNo;
    double Balance;
    double TotalDeposit;
    double TotalWithdrawal;
    Transaction Trans;
    Transaction TransactionList[100];
    int TransactionCount;   
};

struct Transaction
{
    string TransactionDate;
    string TransactionDescription;
    double TransactionAmount;
};
Customer* CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin);

Transaction* CreateTransaction(const string& date, const string& description, const double& amount);

Account* CreateAccount(const Customer& holder, const string& number, const string& date, const double&balance, const double& deposit, const double& withdraw);

void RecordDeposit(Account* account, Transaction* transaction);

void RecordWithdraw(Account* account, Transaction* transaction);

void PrintReport(Account* account);


int main()
{
    Customer* Mary = CreateCustomer("Mary Jones", "235718", "5074");
    Customer* John = CreateCustomer("John Smith", "375864", "3251");

    Account* MaryAccount = CreateAccount(*Mary, "06-3121-10212357", "01/03/2014", 100, 100, 0);
    Account* JohnAccount = CreateAccount(*John, "06-3121-10213758", "10/03/2014", 0, 0, 0);

    RecordDeposit(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("02/03/2014", "Deposit", 90) );
    RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("04/03/2014", "ATM Withdrawal", 150) );
    RecordDeposit(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Deposit", 20) );
    RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Withdraw", 100) );
    RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Withdraw", 50) );
    RecordDeposit(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("11/03/2014", "Deposit", 20) );
    RecordDeposit(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("12/03/2014", "Deposit", 80) );
    RecordWithdraw(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("12/03/2014", "Withdraw", 50) );

    return 0;
}

Customer* CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin)
{
    Customer *c = new Customer;

    c->CustomerName = name;
    c->UserID = id;
    c->Pin = pin;

    return c;
}

Transaction* CreateTransaction(const string& date, const string& description, const double& amount)
{
    Transaction *t = new Transaction;

    t->TransactionDate = date;
    t->TransactionDescription = description;
    t->TransactionAmount = amount;

    return t;
}

Account* CreateAccount(const Customer& holder, const string& number, const string& date, const double&balance, const double& deposit, const double& withdraw)
{
    Account *a = new Account;

    a->Holder = holder;
    a->AccountNo = number;
    a->Trans.TransactionDate = date;
    a->Balance = balance;
    a->TotalDeposit = deposit;
    a->TotalWithdrawal = withdraw;

    return a;
}

void RecordDeposit(Account* account, Transaction* transaction)
{
}

void RecordWithdraw(Account* account, Transaction* transaction)
{
}


void PrintReport(Account* account)
{
}
```

Comment: 1) Next time, edit your code.
2) Your code leaks memory.  You don't need to create pointers.  Just return the object in your functions.

Comment: Please reduce the question to the minimum. It's too much code.

Comment: Example of what I mean: `Account CreateAccount(const Customer& holder, const string& number, const string& date, const double&balance, const double& deposit, const double& withdraw)`
`{
    Account a;
    a.Holder = holder;
    a.AccountNo = number;
    a.Trans.TransactionDate = date;
    a.Balance = balance;
    //...
    return a;
}`  Note that "a" is an Account object, and is returned by value.  There is nothing wrong with that, but you wanted to look for a problem to a solution by introducing pointers, dynamically allocated memory, and thus, memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted your code, and it didn't compile.  You need to move the Transaction struct to be before the Account struct, as it's using stuff that's in the transaction struct.

Now on to your question, I wouldn't use an array if I could help it to store transactions, I'd use a Vector.  The reason being is that with an array, you'd have to make sure that you have enough space in there to enter the new transaction, then navigate to the next free slot you have.  Which is a fair ammount of code.

But with a vector you could do something like this:

```
struct Transaction
{
    // change this from an array to a vector.
    std::vector<Transaction> transactionList;
};

void RecordDeposit(Account* account, Transaction* transaction)
{
    account->transactionList.push_back(transaction);
}
```

With a vector, you call push_back and it will put it in the next free space.  Without you having to constantly loop over the array and check for the next free space.  Also Vectors can grow as your data grows as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it should be `->transactionList.push_back(...)`. Also, `transactionList` in the OP's code was inside `Account`, not inside `Transaction`.

Comment: The code still has an issue, and I mentioned it in my comments.  The transaction is passed as a pointer, but the vector stores Transaction objects, not pointers.  The OP should not need to use pointers anywhere in this program, just objects and references.